# Help with updating grub and fstab when moving root to another partition on dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, 16.04, mount

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and window 7 on dual boot and the window C (or dev/sda3 on ubuntu) is the boot partition.

The partitions on my disk are as follow
[image]

I was trying to move my root partitions(sda1) to a larger partition(sda4)
So I followed the steps given on the [webpage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MovingLinuxPartition)

I was able to complete till steps 4 successfully.
In the steps 5(Update grub and fstab) I didn't understand how to mount partition via gnome -> Places so I searched the web and mounted /dev/sda4 by
typing the following commands mentioned on [this](https://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/mount-partitions-in-terminal-fstab/) webpage.
[image]

As mentioned in the Ubuntu Help article I tried running

> gksu gedit /media//boot/grub/grub.cfg &

Where instead of  I put my /dev/sda4 partitions uuid and it opened a blank grub.cfg file. So I tried running the command

> gksu gedit /mnt/test_root/boot/grub/grub.cfg &

And It opened the grub.cfg in the new partition and after that i am not able to understand what to do i.e what all uuid to change and I didn't find any (hdX,Y)" to replace as per the article so I have uploaded the grub file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0PsWY1BPXF8UHY1QlBWOFZwZ1k) so can anyone tell me what all things I have to change.
I have replaced the uuid of /dev/sda1 to

And Also it would be nice if anyone can tell me what the author of the article on ubuntu help meant by *mounting the partition via gnome->places*?

Answer (score 1):

At first a warning, this are the first line of grub.conf-file:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#
```

So please don't mess this up, you would make your Ubuntu unbootable.

In your config-file you will see many places with this string:

```
'hd0,msdos1'
```

In your case you have to replace that with

```
'hd0,msdos4',
```

Use the replace-option in the edit-menu of your texteditor, this will make sure that the string is replaced everywhere in the config-file

in the file /etc/fstab you have to change the UUID of the /-partition
Example:

```
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=71d24e33-33cc-4815-83cd-92ce3c141be2   /   ....
```

Find out the UUID of sda4 with

```
sudo blkid
```

look for sda4, copy the UUID and paste it over the old UUID.
That's it...

"mount the partition via gnome -> Places option" means to open the places-menu in unity-panel, all volumes are listed there and your volume would be automounted with a single mouseclick (would be mounted to /media/. But that's not important anymore, you have the volume successfully mounted already.

Now you can follow the instructions in step 6 of the community help wiki, i am sure you are able to do...
One  hint for step 6: [instance] is i386-pc in your case...

Good luck...